# How to stop shrinking effect on header on scroll?

Tags: css, header, navbar, nav

I consider myself a webdev noob and I learn better by messing around with existing examples. I've been looking for a way of making a navbar transparent which then transforms to a solid background upon scrolling down. I found exactly what I wanted in a free template. It has one feature I dont want though - it shrinks the navbar upon scrolling and I would rather keep the navbar the same height. Here is the code (my first attempt with Codepen so dont laugh!):

http://codepen.io/quanticspaz/pen/zGWXYM

```
// jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
  } else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
  }
});

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
  $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Is it CSS or JS thats causing the shrinking effect on scroll? Please put me out of my misery... I've been messing with this for a couple of hours now and its driving me bonkers!

Comment: This seems to be working well. What's your problem?

Comment: When writing a question, try to avoid making it personal. For example, there is no need to tell us you are a "noob"... that is already implied by your code :P

Comment: I suspect the shrinking is what happens which this class `top-nav-collapse` is applied. It's probably changing the height...you need to find that class and override it.

Comment: @musefan Frankly, it doesn't look like noob code to me...but you are correct that the comment is not required.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Maybe you are also too noob to know better... or maybe that part of the comment was a joke. Take your pick ;)

Comment: @musefan I don't think 20k makes me a noob so I'm going to assume you attempted a joke...and missed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS you will find a class called `top-nav-collapse`, this is currently being set when the page is scrolled and has a `padding` property which is what is causing the shrinking effect. Remove this padding and your problem is solved:

```
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    background: #000;
}
```

[Here is an update to your codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGWeZe)

Comment: I cant believe it was that easy! I would never have found it though so many thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what developer tools are for...it does make it easy.